# Can not add object inside a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, objective-c-blocks, quickblox

I am running a block to fetch all users connect with a `Quickblox` account.But after adding user's login name to the mutable array, the count of the array is still showing zero or an empty array.

```
   QBGeneralResponsePage *page = [QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:1 perPage:10];
    [QBRequest usersForPage:page successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBGeneralResponsePage *pageInformation, NSArray *users) {

        for (int i =0; i<users.count; i++) {
            QBUUser *user = [[QBUUser alloc]init];
            [_contacts insertObject:user.login atIndex:i];
        }

    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

    }];
```

Comment: where are you using the array in relation to this code? aka where are you checking the size of the array, if the `usersForPage` function is asynchronous, if you were trying to access the array directly afterwards it would be empty, as the completion handler for the method has not executed yet

Comment: I am using this code in viewDidLoad ,where '_contacts' is the array, i want to use the array in tableVIewCell's labelText....I think you are right the function is asynchronous ..what should I do?

Comment: hmm, hard to tell from just this snippet, but i assume your table is basing its cells on the `_contacts` array, maybe you just need to reload the tableview from the completion handler and it will just work. otherwise you may need to do whatever else you need doing inside the completion handler and not after the function call

Comment: see my answer for a more clear explanation of what i mean

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are trying to use the array before the completion handler has actually executed

```
QBGeneralResponsePage *page = [QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:1 perPage:10];
[QBRequest usersForPage:page successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBGeneralResponsePage *pageInformation, NSArray *users) {

    for (int i =0; i<users.count; i++) {
        QBUUser *user = [[QBUUser alloc]init];
        [_contacts insertObject:user.login atIndex:i];
    }

    [self.tableview reloadData]; //possible fix

    //move any other code that uses _contacts here, or call a function that will deal with _contacts

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

}];

//if you are trying to use _contacts here, its size will be 0 because the above completion handler has not executed yet. 
//consider moving whatever is here into the completion handler above
```

Comment: I tried it ..but the problem is I also have to set the row's count according to array count..but numberOf Rows method get called before the block execution.

Comment: hmm, but that should only be triggered from the `[self.tableview reloadData];` which at that point, the `_contacts` array will be populated if you have the code like i have shown. are you sure you are not reloading the data somewhere else, or using some other tableview method that could be causing that to happen prematurely?

Comment: numberOfRows may be called on the tableviews initial creation regardless, so probably will fire prematurely, but then will fire again once the `[self.tableview reloadData];` from the completion block happens, then your table should report the correct number of rows from that function if its just returning the size of _contacts

Answer (score 0):

It is all about logic, I figured it out as it clicks in my mind a simple one line solution.

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
            //cellLabelText will not get filled by array until the block api gets data in array

            if (_contacts.count>0) {
                   cell.textLabel.text = [arrContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }

            return cell;
```